# GTK+ CMake setup

Tags: c++, cmake, gtk

I'm mainly working with Java and Gradle, but for my current project I have to use C++ with CMake and thus I would like to have some feedback on my current folder structure and project setup.

```
root_project
  |─── .gitignore
  |─── CMakeLists.txt
  |─── build
  |─── src
  |     |     |─── [...].hpp
  |     └─── [...].cpp
  |─── tests
  └─── vendor
```

The project is intended to use C++17 and work with Clang and GCC. I'm currently not sure how I should add a test framework to CMake.

CMakeLists.txt

```
# set the minimum required version of cmake needed by this CMake project.
# this command is needed to set version and policy
# settings before invoking other commands
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# set the name of the project, the version and which languages
# are needed to build this project
# this command must immediately follow the cmake_minimum_required command
project (Editor LANGUAGES CXX)

# GTK 3 dependency
FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

# Setup CMake to use GTK+, tell the compiler where to look for headers
# and to the linker where to look for libraries
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# Add other flags to the compiler
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

# some test warning levels for GCC
set(WARNING_LEVELS_GCC
    -Werror
)
set(WARNING_LEVELS_GCC_DEBUG
    -Wfloat-equal
    -Wextra
    -Wall
    -Wundef
    -Wshadow
    -Wpointer-arith
    -Wcast-align
    -Wstrict-overflow=5
    -Wwrite-strings
    #-Waggregate-return
    -Wcast-qual
    -Wswitch-default
    -Wswitch-enum
    -Wconversion
)    

# include directory for third party libraries
include_directories(vendor/)

# add an executable target with one source file
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} 
    src/Editor.cpp
    src/Editor.hpp
    src/main.cpp
    src/test1.hpp
    src/test1.cpp
)

# Link the target to the GTK+ libraries
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
target_compile_options(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${WARNING_LEVELS_GCC} $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${WARNING_LEVELS_GCC_DEBUG}>)
```

The commands I build the project with:

```
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG ..
cmake --build .
```